# how to properly use np.isnan() to detect nan elements in array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find clusters using DBSCAN from sickit.Here is the code -

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=.2, min_samples=5).fit(p)
 cluster_labels = db.labels_
 num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))
 clusters = pd.Series([p[cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
 print(len(clusters))
 C = np.empty(shape=(len(clusters), 2), dtype=np.float16)
 for i in range(len(clusters)):
     C[i] = np.mean(clusters[i], axis=0)
 print(C)
```

here p is a 2d array.So if i run the code above i get -

And i get this runtime warning -

```
 C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\REALDEPTH\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:3257: 

RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
      out=out, **kwargs)

C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\REALDEPTH\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:154: 

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)

4

[[-1.369   1.895 ]
 [ 0.2095  0.763 ]
 [-0.572   1.688 ]
 [    nan     nan]]
```

so this problem arises as np.mean cant compute **Mean of empty slice** **so to avoid nan values**, I do this -

```
    print(len(clusters))
    C = np.empty(shape=(len(clusters), 2))
    for i in range(len(clusters)):
        if not np.isnan(C[i][0]):
            print(np.isnan(C[i][0]))
            C[i] = np.mean(clusters[i], axis=0, dtype=np.float64)
            print(C[i][0])

    print(C)
```

and get this output -

```
    C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\REALDEPTH\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:3257:             
  RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  out=out, **kwargs)
  C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\REALDEPTH\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:154: 
  RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
4
False
-1.4311423570879045
False
0.14525776544683858
False
-0.7161999985172942
False
nan
[[-1.43114236  1.9280001 ]
[ 0.14525777  0.79508425]
[-0.7162      1.73658117]
[        nan         nan]]
```

**what is strange above is , it is only supposed to print the C[i][0] element if it was not nan. but np.isnan(C[i][0]) returns false and still the value is nan and it gets printed.
my input data doesnt contain any nan values.i am certain about that.**

Please tell me what i am missing.Also feel free tell me if any part of my question is unclear.

Comment: Have you looked at `np.nanmean`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter out `nan` values, here's a quick workaround:

```
import numpy as np
C = np.array([x for x in C if np.std(x) > 0])
```

I used `np.std` because to make list comprehension work we need to use some function which returns a scalar value, hence you could use any function like mean, var etc.

Hope it helps.